# How to display two string from two different lists in python?

Tags: python

If I have 2 lists: 
`x = [1, 2, 3, 4]` 
`y = [a, b, c, d]` 
How can I display something like: 
`1 - a, 2 - b, 3 - c, 4 - d`?

Comment: Check out [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both lists together. You also have the option to iterate over the range of indices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: Syed Shahzer This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```py
print([str(x[i]) + "-" + str(y[i]) for i in range(len(x))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if your two list's lengths are same.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
st = ""
for i, j in zip(a,b):
    st += f", {i} - {j} "
new_st = st.lstrip(",")
print(new_st)
```